# Error "Missing \endcsname inserted" when including PDF using \includegraphics

Tags: errors, includegraphics

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=4cm]{2.pdf}
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The error message is:

> Missing \endcsname inserted.
>    
>                      \relax 
>   l.334 ...udegraphics[width=3cm, height=4cm]{1.jpg}

but, if add only a picture, then it is ok.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=4cm]{1.jpg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is ok. But why does the first one give an error message?

Comment: I know that the `graphicx` package is fantastic, but this is no reason to load it more than once.

Comment: It is also better to not specify both the width and height of an image, this will distort the image. If you must specify both, add at least `keepaspectratio`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the `turkish` language option makes `=` into an active character, essentially ruining any key=val interface (as they assume `=` to be a normal character).

The standard method of dealing with this is `\shorthandoff{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \shorthandoff{=}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=4cm]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Used like this, it temporarily (inside  this `figure` env) deactivates `=` making it behave normally, thus `width=3cm` works again.

The documentation for `turkish` babel (`texdoc babel-turkish`) mentions that the activation of `=` is potentially dangerous, and you can use

```
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
```

to just active `:!`, leaving `=` alone.